# Working with a MSSQL DB and a MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, sql-server, system-administration

I am working on a `PHP script` in a server. I have two databases:

1. The first one is a `MySQL DB` and it is already imported to my server, so it is connected successfully.
2. The second one is a `MSSQL DB` and I would like to import it from another server to mine.

The problem is that I don't if I can install MSSQL somehow to the server and I haven't found any solution while searching for it or if I should connect to the two servers simultaneously. Could you maybe help me with that? What is the best solution?

I hope it is not that simple question, but I am a bit new in server administration.

Comment: Which server you have Windows or Linux?

Comment: One is Windows and one Linux

Comment: You cannot install MSSQL To Linux. To import database in MSSQL, all you have to do is, Install MSSQL on Windows server, install "SQL Server Management Studio" and with both you get ability to restore the database, so use your BAK file from other server and restore it on your windows machine.

Comment: The only thing is that I want to insert it to the Linux Server and I have tried to transform it to MySQL, but I encounter some errors.

Comment: please share error, so I can tell what might be wrong.

Comment: The error is that I cannot use MSSQL in my script PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mssql_connect()

Comment: I don't completely understand your goal, and it isn't clear if your SQL Server database is actually running and available on the Windows server, or if you just have a backup. It also isn't clear if your problem is the PHP error, or if you're asking for a general way to migrate SQL Server to MySQL. I suggest you focus on one problem at a time, and be as specific as possible about that one issue.

Comment: I think it is not a php error. My problem is to import the MSSQL DB into my linux server.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP installation doesn't have MsSQl Extension available. Install MSSQL extension for PHP and it will work. Usually you just have to open a line in php.ini and make sure that mssql module is there in extension folder. restart web server and it will work

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't  enable the **MSSQL**   extension in `php.ini` file.

**In Linux**

- You will find this in **php.ini** file :      `;extension=mssql.so`
  and replace with this :   `extension=mssql.so`( just remove the
  semicolon to enable.)
- You will find a file in (if you are using xampp linux)
  lampp/etc/freetds.conf file. In this file you need to add the following configuration.

  add this:

  [DevSqlServer]

  host = 172.16.1.123

  instance = DEVAPSERVER

  port = 1433

  tds version = 7.0
- Restart your server. and your php code should be like this.
- Here you can  see what i have done. **DevSqlSerrver** i have given in
  the freetds.cof. So i need to give the server name that what i have
  given in freetds.conf.

  ```
    // Connect to MSSQL
     $connection = mssql_connect("DevSqlServer", 'sa', '****');
     $db_connect=mssql_select_db("DBname",$connection);
  ```

And you can access MSSQL Server database.

For more info:

[Link1](http://www.dotvoid.com/2010/01/adding-support-for-ms-sql-server-to-php-in-linux/)

[Link2](http://kmaiti.blogspot.in/2010/08/how-to-install-mssql-php-extension-on.html)